# GWT: Save URL in browser's bookmark section

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, web

I have a bookmark button in a certain widget in my GWT application. When the user clicks the bookmark button, it generates URL. I need to store this URL in browser(firefox/chrome) bookmark section.

I can use the History class to store a history item, but I don't want that. I simply need that the URL i generate gets saved in the browser's bookmark section or atleast prompts user to save my URL in bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

The most you can do is show them the URL and/or put it in a link so they can copy it or right-click it (can't remember if you can add a link to bookmarks, at least not in Chrome for Android).

Have a look at how Google Maps for example handles the situation, or Google Groups, UX-wise.